# What is an algorithm for weighted shuffling that scales well?

Tags: algorithm, random, shuffle, weighted

## Setup

**Items** in a **set** have a **weight** property that can be set by an admin **user**. Items with more weight are more likely to achieve top position in a randomized **list** served to public **visitors**. Every item has a chance (however miniscule) to appear in any position.

What algorithm would ensure that changing an item’s weight would achieve a consistent result regardless of set size?

I know I’m out of my depth, but I don’t want to assume that the actual probability structure implied by the [basic algorithm](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/233541) (Attempt 1) is valid. Am I tilting at windmills here?* Is my method flawed? Are my conclusions solid?

#### Parameters for success

1. **A heavier weight makes a higher position more likely.**
2. **Each item must have at least a small chance of appearing in any position on the list.** (This rules out a “rank class” or “rank quota” type of approach, which could end up mandating that items of a low rank never appear, or a high rank containing a single item always appear.)
3. **Set size should not affect one weight’s effect relative to another weight.** Set size will of course affect a single item’s overall chances. I mean that in the set `[a:2, b:2, c:2, d:2, e:3, f:3]`, the difference in chance between `b` and `e` will be the same as in the set `[a:2, b:2, c:3, d:3, e:3, f:3]` (same length, different sum) and the same as in the set `[a:1, b:2, e:3, f:6]` (different length, same sum).
4. **Only the *difference* in weight matters**, not the actual amount of weight. In the set `[3,3,17,17]`, bumping up the last item to 19 should have as much effect as bumping the first item up to 5; and the set `[1,3]` should behave similarly to `[3,5]`. This is so that users don’t have to understand the whole set to make an efficient change.

---

## Attempts

##### 1: Linear weights (standard method)

```
function linear_ratio($weight_set, $weight) {
    $sum = 0;
    foreach ($weight_set as $item) $sum += $item;
    return $weight / $sum;
}
```

1. [PASS] A heavier weight makes a higher position more likely.
2. [PASS] Heaviest weight still has a chance of bottom position.
3. [PASS] Weights 3 and 3+2 have the same relative probabilities regardless of how large the set is.
4. [FAIL] 3→5 is a 167% change, but 17→19 is a 112% change.

##### 2: Exponential weights

```
function exponential_ratio($weight_set, $weight) {
    $sum = 0;
    foreach ($weight_set as $item) $sum += (2 ** $item);
    $weight = 2 ** $weight;
    return $weight / $sum;
}
```

This solves the 4th parameter, but the base (2) is arbitrary yet exponentially impactful.

1. [PASS] A heavier weight makes a higher position more likely.
2. [PASS] Heaviest weight still has a chance of bottom position.
3. [PASS] Weights 3 and 3+2 have the same relative probabilities regardless of how large the set is.
4. [PASS] 3→5 is a 400% change, and 17→19 is still a 400% change.

##### 3: Set size as a parameter

```
function based_exponential_ratio($weight_set, $weight) {
    $set_size = count($weight_set);
    $sum = 0;
    foreach ($weight_set as $item) $sum += $set_size ** $item;
    $weight = $set_size ** $item;
    return $weight / $sum;
}
```

This just switches out one problem (the arbitrary base) for another. Given a set of 100 items, adding 1 more shouldn’t make much difference, but set size + 1 increases weight’s effect exponentially (thus reducing randomization).

##### 4: Magnitude of set size as a parameter

I do care about adding 500 more items to the set of 100. So do I care *when set size changes by an order of magnitude*? “Take the natural log of the set size and raise it to the *weight* power”? My mental model can’t progress any further than this point, but I would have thought that taking an exponent of a log would be counter-productive.

Comment: "I considered making the set size the base" This paragraph makes no sense to me. I can't interpret what it means. Can you try to reword it?

Comment: What does it mean for results to be "consistent"?

Comment: It is very unclear what you want. is it selection with replacement or without? Would selection affect weight? Could you put out what probabilities you would like for your example?

Comment: Another interesting variant of the exponent would be `(2^(1/10))^N`, in which case increasing `N` by one bumps the weight by +7%, and increasing `N` by 10 bumps the weight by +100%.  That doesn't really solve your problems though.

Comment: Another interesting idea would be to generate a random float number between `0` and `M` for each entry, then increase each items value by `N`, and then sort them.  If `M=count`, then `N+1` moves the item up one entry higher on average, but no guarantees. Different `M/count` ratios control how many rows an `N+1` increases on average.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: something about this suggests an XY problem ....?

Comment: Where does the fourth parameter come from? Why do you want an additive change to a weight to have a multiplicative effect? Could you just have the client enter multiplicative changes when they want multiplicative effects?

Comment: @MooingDuck Can you turn each of your variant ideas into an answer? I don’t think I’ve considered either of them, but I can’t be certain without understanding what `N` represents.

Comment: @David The first comment is merely an iteration on your idea#2.  Instead of `(2 ** $item);`, you use `(2**(1/10)) ** $item`. That way each `+1` is less impactful than 2x, giving more fine grained control: 3→5 is a 14.87% change, and 17→19 is still a 14.87% change.

Comment: I can't post answers now, but the tldr; for the second comment is: "for each entry, `$listweight = rand(0, count($weight_set)) +$weight;`, and then sort the entries by `listweight`. The net result is that +1 `$weight` will make that entry display one row higher *on average*. This is pretty intuitive for users.

Comment: @MooingDuck I understand now. I’m sorry you can’t post them as answers, but I can’t get the question reopened. The accepted answer pointed out a logic flaw, and so was the most helpful answer posted before the question was closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exponential approach you have is the most reasonable given your conditions.

The way you are stating your final condition is not realistic. Generally, examining the percentage change in probability is not a useful way of looking at it.

> [FAIL] If the set is [2,2,13,13], incrementing the lightest value by 1 changes it from 4/16392 to 8/16400—a 199.9% change. Incrementing the heaviest value by 1 changes it from 8192/16392 to 16384/24584—only a 133.4% change.

What if you have two products, and your initial weights are set to produce starting probabilities of `[99/100, 1/100]`? Then suppose there is a real number `dw` such that incrementing the weight of the second product by `dw` takes the probabilities to `[95/100, 5/100]`. That's a "400% increase" in the probability of the second product. There's no way to increase the probability of the first product in a remotely similar way.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, any growing function will do. E.g. you could use subtraction and inverse weights.

Total in the set are N items.

A, B, C, ... >> 500. a, b, c, ... are your counters

P<sub>a</sub> ~ 1/(A-a)

P<sub>b</sub> ~ 1/(B-b)

...

Total = Sum(i=[1...N]) P<sub>i</sub>

Sampling probability

SP<sub>i</sub> = P<sub>i</sub>/Total

Incrementing a, b, c, ... will increase sampling probability. A, B, C, ... could be the same relatively large number

UPDATE

so instead of

f(x) = c x

or

f(x) = exp(c x)

monotonically growing function would be

f(x) = 1/(c - x) for some large c

UPDATE II

Another quite common monotonically growing function to try is

f(x) = x<sup>c</sup>